# Echo randomly named file name

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a jQuery/PHP signature module on my website, called 'HTML5 Signature Pad to Image'

On iPad, a client signes the box with his finger/stylus and upon clicking 'Submit', PHP creates a random named file, and saves it on a designated folder.

I need to have that file name echoed anywhere on the page after clicking submit.

How is this possible?

PHP:

```
$random= rand(111111111,999999999);
$dd_savePath=str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__))."/signatures";
$prependSig=($random.date(Y.m.d)).'.png';


* Finally, save her
*/
$file="{$dd_savePath}/".($action=="sig" ? "{$prependSig}{$fileName}" : "{$prependTxt}{$fileName}");
if(@file_put_contents($file, $decodeData)) {
    @chmod($file,0777);
```

(This is a postAction method that was suggested by the 'How to' that came with the plugin)

```
    dd_doPostAction = {
       submit : function(t) {

myFunctionCall(t);

} }
```

Comment: don't generate filenames like this. you'd be surprised at how quickly you'll end up with duplicate names and trashing a previously uploaded file.

Comment: What would you suggest to be the proper way to generate them? it needs to be per client based naming.

Comment: You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php to generate a unique file name, this will not colide.

Comment: if you're storing details about the file in a database, then use at least the associated record's ID number somewhere in your filename. Randomness is fine, as long as it's not the ONLY component of the filename. e.g. `$id-$random.png` would eliminate any chance of collisions, and the random part will greatly reduce the chance of outsiders guessing what the filename is.

Comment: thank you for this, i will implement it. any chance on figuring how to echo the final name when submitting?